# Group by/aggregate multiple variables

Tags: r

Aggregate results from a table in R

I'm pretty sure the answer is simple, but I'm having trouble to properly describe the problem...

I have the following table:

| Species | Round | # of individuals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 2 |
| A | 2 | 2 |

I have two expected outputs: one which shows the sum of individuals, and other which shows the number of occurrences. Both per Round, grouped by Species, as it follows:

| # individuals | Round 1 | Round 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 0 |

| # Occurences | Round 1 | Round 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 0 |

I think it must be done with a combination of AGGREGATE and GROUP BY, but couldn't find the exact syntax. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution.
`aggregate` the individuals by all other variables, applying `sum` and `length` in the 1st and 2nd cases, respectively. Then reshape to wide format.

```r
df1 <- "Species     Round   'individuals'
A   1   3
A   1   2
B   1   2
A   2   2"
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(df1), header = TRUE)

agg1 <- aggregate(individuals ~ ., df1, sum)
agg1
#>   Species Round individuals
#> 1       A     1           5
#> 2       B     1           2
#> 3       A     2           2

agg2 <- aggregate(individuals ~ ., df1, length)
agg2
#>   Species Round individuals
#> 1       A     1           2
#> 2       B     1           1
#> 3       A     2           1

reshape(agg1, direction = "wide", idvar = "Species", timevar = "Round")
#>   Species individuals.1 individuals.2
#> 1       A             5             2
#> 2       B             2            NA

reshape(agg2, direction = "wide", idvar = "Species", timevar = "Round")
#>   Species individuals.1 individuals.2
#> 1       A             2             1
#> 2       B             1            NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Perfect, what I missed is the 'reshape' step. Thank you!